# How to do get_users() with multiple meta_keys

Tags: users

In the codex it says its possible to do get_users() with multiple meta keys by using the meta_query parameter but it doesn't explain how. Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it mentions in the Codex page for [`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users), it works the same as a `WP_Query` [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters), see that page for full arguments list and examples.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'some_key',
            'value' => 'foo',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'another_key',
            'value' => array( 'bar', 'baz' )
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work with the 'NOT EXISTS' operator as the value of `'compare'`. If I want to return all users that DON'T have a specific key, should this work? `array('key'=>'some_key','compare'=>'NOT EXISTS')`

Comment: @emersonthis 10+ years later.. :) it should work. But guys be aware that when you use 2 or more query (inner)array, there is the 'relation' parameter, is set to 'AND' by default between them(in the outer array).
read more --> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters